# Merge Sort - Algorithm not showing correct number of swaps

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort

The merge sort algorithm change counter below is not returning the correct value.

```
public class Main {

    static int comparisons = 0;
    static int changes = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {3, 8, 5, 1};

        sort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Comparisons = " + comparisons);
        System.out.println("Changes = " + changes);
    }

    public static void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r) {
        // Find sizes of two subarrays to be merged
        int n1 = m - l + 1;
        int n2 = r - m;

        /* Create temp arrays */
        int L[] = new int[n1];
        int R[] = new int[n2];

        /*Copy data to temp arrays*/
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; ++i) {
            L[i] = arr[l + i];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; ++j) {
            R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j];
        }

        /* Merge the temp arrays */
        // Initial indexes of first and second subarrays
        int i = 0, j = 0;

        // Initial index of merged subarray array
        int k = l;
        while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
            if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
                arr[k] = L[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                arr[k] = R[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
            comparisons++;
        }

        /* Copy remaining elements of L[] if any */
        while (i < n1) {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }

        /* Copy remaining elements of R[] if any */
        while (j < n2) {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }

    // Main function that sorts arr[l..r] using
    // merge()
    public static void sort(int arr[], int l, int r) {
        if (l < r) {
            changes++;
            // Find the middle point
            int m = l + (r - l) / 2;

            // Sort first and second halves
            sort(arr, l, m);
            sort(arr, m + 1, r);

            // Merge the sorted halves
            merge(arr, l, m, r);
        }

    }
     
}
```

I put a counter to know how many changes are being made in the process of sorting arrays with random integer values, but the value of changes in the counter is not corresponding to the expected result. I did it on paper and the result of exchanges obtained was 4, but the counter returns 3. To test I used this array {3, 8, 5, 1}. I'm also in doubt if the number of comparisons returned in the other counter is correct. Why is the counter not returning the correct value?

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: What do you define as an "exchange" in the context of merge sort, which doesn't perform swaps like some other sort algorithms?

Comment: Yes, it's a real question. I rephrased the question.

Comment: The "exchange" happens when two values of the array to be sorted are not in ascending order, so the algorithm reverses the position of both so that they are sorted correctly. I don't know if you could understand.

Comment: My guess is the goal is to count inversions, not moves or exchanges. Link to [example code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inversion-count-in-array-using-merge-sort), the second example.